# What's wrong with this hash?

Tags: hash, hashtable

What's wrong with this hash function? Specifically, what will happen when N=127 is passed in?

```
int hash3(char *k, int N)
{
    char *c;  int h = 0;

    for (c = k; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        h = h | *c;
    }
    return (h % N);
}
```

This was a question that came up in a practice exam (with no solutions unfortunately). As I understand it, the function is using bitwise or to  convert a string into an integer, and place it in a table of size N, but I don't really know why it would be faulty? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try inputting some long sentence and see what would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Monotonous functions like bitwise OR is not suitable for calculating hash.

As you know, OR operator "|" work as follows.

0 | 0 = 0

0 | 1 = 1

1 | 0 = 1

1 | 1 = 1

Number of 1's never been deceased, so OR operation is monotonous incremental function.

If OR operation applied repeatedly to many data, the result may become '1' in high possibility.

If you apply long sequence of characters to your code, you may have 127 ('1111111' in binary) as result frequently or almost of time.

bitwise AND is not suitable also, because AND is monotonous decremental function.

XOR is most suitable bitwise operation for calculating Hash.